# List number of duplicate values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following a Rails ActiveRecord association where a lesson has_many books, and books belong_to a lesson. I want to run a SQL command that will tell me how many lessons have multiple books that belong to that lesson.

Ex: Lesson 1 has books 1 and 2, and I want to see how many times that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[#having](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-having) will let you do a [#group](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group) that filters out Lessons that only have one Book.

```
Book.group(:lesson_id).having("count(lesson_id) > 1").count
```

Answer (score 1):

`Book.group(:lesson_id).count` will return a hash with the `lesson_id` as key and the number of books as value.

You could also implement a `counter_cache` as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) under section 4.1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Like the first answer said, a counter cache or using group and count is the best way to go for simply getting counts.

But If you are wanting to actually output the book names that belong to a lesson as opposed to just a count in the console or in your view you can do something similar to:

```
Lesson.all.each do |lesson|
  puts lesson.books.map { |b| b.name }.join(", ")
end
```