# Finding records where NONE of the record's association attribute is of a given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
class Project
      has_many :quotes
      scope :available, ->(business_id) { joins(:quotes).where.not(quotes: { business_id: business_id }) }
      scope :active, ->(business_id) { joins(:quotes).where(quotes: { business_id: business_id }) }
end

class Quote
      belongs_to :project
end
```

Hi, I'm trying to define an `available` scope which returns a relation of `Project` records which don't have a `Quote` for a given `business_id`. I tried using the above scope, but it's returning an empty relation?

A similar `active` scope seems to work fine. The only difference here is the `.not()` clause.

Any ideas? Do I have to write raw SQL for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31256399/2697183

Comment: @AbM That's not really relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it.

```
  scope :available, ->(business_id) {where.not(Quote.where("quotes.project_id = projects.id and quotes.business_id = ?", business_id).exists)}
```